# remote-compiling PhoneGap Symbian (Qt) fails?

Tags: symbian, qt-creator, cordova

The new QtCreator 2.0.1 has new remote-compilation facilities that allow building of Symbian Qt apps on Mac and Linux hosts.

Unfortunately, the phonegap [code drop for Symbian/Qt](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494811/PhoneGap-Symbian-%28Qt%29) doesn't remote-compile.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the connection to remote compiler successful, but the build fails?  Can you supply the build error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection works to the remote compiler.

Here is a screen grab of the build errors I get with

- Qt Creator 2.0.1
- OSX 10.6.7
- Qt 4.6.3 with Mobilitu 1.0.2 - S60 5th edition release 
  (but got the same errors with 1.1.2experimental...)
- PhoneGap Qt cloned today from Git

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having this same issue with QtCreator and the Remote Compiler, but not using Phone Gap. I think this is more a Mac OS X thing. Is the missing directory within a

```
symbian {
...
}
```

scope in your .pro file? Easiest 'fix' is to pull it out of that scope block, unless you are cross compiling to other platforms and need separate source directories.